# How can I play music from the user's music library in my own app?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm doing this for my alarm app, so I need to have the user click a button which will open up his or her music library, and then select a song from it. Then I need to take whatever song was selected, and add it to my tableview of available sounds.

Once that's done, I can figure out how to code the rest. I just need to know how to open the music library, and then select a song and pass it into my tableview.

Comment: `MPMediaPickerController ` is that you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I'm looking for, thank you